# How to import values into a column from another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I created an Access Database and I wish to import a subset of data from a master table into a smaller table using SQL Queries. Basically, I want the smaller (Customer) table to reflect any changes made in the bigger (Total) table.

I tried the following code:

```
UPDATE Customer SET Brand = 
     (SELECT Brand FROM Total WHERE Chance = -1) ; Chance is a binary column
WHERE EXIST (SELECT Brand FROM Total WHERE Chance  = -1);
```

, but I get an error: "operation must use an updateable query" and my file is not a read-only file.

Is there another Query that I can use to perform the same task?

Comment: update, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks Ryan for making my code more legible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update statement in MS Access database should looks like:

```
UPDATE Customer AS C
INNER JOIN Total AS T ON T.PK = C.FK
SET C.Brand = T.Brand
WHERE T.Chance=-1;
```

Where:

**PK** = Primary Key

**FK** = Foreign Key

Comment: You're very welcome ;) If solution was helpful, please accept my answer.